# How to rename several Net Labels in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium

I am using Altium Designer 16.1 for a project which has about 6 thousands of components, so I have many Net Lables(at first I designed a small circuit in a schematic page then by copy and paste I create the whole project).
I used Annotate Schematics option in the "Tools" menu to rename the components, Is there any option to rename the Net Lables automatically like annotate option?

Comment: Rename them how?  Do you have busses and want to rename all the wires in the bus, keeping the numbers the same?  Do you want to make the net labels match the pin labels on a specific IC?

Comment: Why do you need to rename the net labels? Do you have them named based on the components they're connected to? Altium does this automatically. If you name them based on their functions, that shouldn't change based on the component designators.

Comment: Altium has a variety of tools that may be relevant - for example, check the documentation for the SCH List (http://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/Sch_Pnl-SCHList((SCH+List))_AD) , especially the sections starting at "Modification Using an Expression".  Smart Paste (ctrl-shift-v) is also helpful, E.G. if you want to automatically expand a bus into individual wires or to create ports that match net labels or vice-versa.  However, without more detail in the question, I can't give a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks every body. I solved it by creating that small circuit with 'PORT' instead of Net Labels then in another sheet, the main sheet, I have used it, hierarchical design.

Answer (score 1):

EEK.. unless you can edit that in a text file or something you may be out of luck..

For future reference, the better method for something like this is to make your design hierarchical.

Create a single page with the common circuit with an associated symbol, then instantiate N of those symbols on an interconnecting schematic page.

The software should handle the rest.

Comment: Don't know if the advice about multiple copies of a schematic applies to OP's project, but if it does it's certainly helpful.